# How to configure Codelite "Syntax highliting" for c++?

Tags: c++, codelite

Is it possible to configure Codelite to highlight syntax error in C++ like in most other IDE?

Answer (score 0):

If you use cmake as your C++ build system you can generate the necessary codelite files to achieve what you want.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/CodeLite.html